# Use enter key in selenium through robot class in python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Sumit.Kumar\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\sumit\chromedriver.exe")
#driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=DE")
driver.maximize_window()


val = "Football"

driver.find_element_by_id("input-254").send_keys(val)

time.sleep(1)
val1 = "Cricket"

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="explorepage-content-header"]/explore-pills/div/button""").send_keys(val1)
```

**
    In second container i want to press the down key and then enter . I want to press the down key and enter key. Please help me out.Thanks in advance.**

Comment: "Is not working". Make sutre you explain as clearly as you can what isn't working. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, and what you tried.

Comment: Why did you inport robot and then overrided it by creating a new class that is completly out of syntax ?? ( It looks like you dont know how classes works in pythong and what object is good for ... ) I am sorry if I am wrong .. Anyways Delete that class robot if you are importing it from somewhere .. and test it out

Comment: Sorry my bad i am newbie in this..... i removed robot class just want to press enter in second container. I tried enter() key also but its not working